# qtp unable to call proper Action depending on the input from excel sheet for "yes" status

Tags: automation, qtp

I'm trying to call some Actions depending the "Yes" status and using Column names, e.g Login, Header,Footer etc. as below sheet ([link](https://plus.google.com/photos/113376360790447215135/albums/6117462136377122673/6117462135964446082?pid=6117462135964446082&oid=113376360790447215135))

[image: Image of the excel sheet]

Below is the code: (skipping the excel load and other part) and Action for each Column name are present e.g Login, Header, Footer etc

```
iRowCount= DataTable.GetSheet("Main").GetRowCount()
iColumnCount=DataTable.GetSheet("Main").GetParameterCount

For iR = 1 To iRowCount
    DataTable.SetCurrentRow iR
    bRun=Datatable.Value("Run","Main")
    If UCase(bRun)= "YES" Then
        For iC = 5 To iColumnCount
         bComponent= Datatable.Value(iC,"Main")

         If ucase(bComponent) ="YES" Then
            sModule=DataTable.GetSheet("Main").GetParameter(iC).Name
            print sModule
            RunAction sModule, oneIteration

         End If

        Next

    End If  
Next
```

Even though the Footer in second row is not "Yes" still the action is been called

I have use Print Statement to show the Action names
 the output is

```
Login
Header
Footer
SecondaryNavigation
Login
Header
Footer
SecondaryNavigation
```

However when i dont use

```
RunAction sModule, oneIteration
```

then the output changes to

```
Login
Header
Footer
SecondaryNavigation
Login
Header
Cookiemessage
SecondaryNavigation
```

I'm not able to find out what is wrong, when i don't call the actions, the code works fine, however when i use Action call to execute, it follows the 1st row status not the 2nd row status

Comment: @Amit, please check the code again,  `ucase(bComponent) ="YES"`, hope  you do understand what this statement does, its converting the the **bComponent** to uppercase and comparing "YES" which is in upper case

Comment: It might be that upon calling the action, all "current" data table rows are re-set to the row that QTP thinks it should be reset to (usually dpeending oin the iteration settings, and on what the current iteration is). (Some QTP versions do this; older ones don´t.) If you pass the row number to the action, and to a SetCurrentRow there, it probably works.

Answer (score 0):

**You have hidden column C.**

So the index for the "footer" column actually is 6, not 5.

**So your loop should iterate from 6 to column count, not 5.**

Experience from many many IT years in the Windows field: Keep looking for Excel columns with width = 0, or you will waste your life looking for bugs which are in reality missing information or wrong column assumptions :O

> Even though the Footer in second row is not "Yes" still the action is
>   been called

This is because actually, due to the quirk just outlined, the "Header" cell value is being used, and it is "Yes" for that row.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however it was not the concern. The problem is in the output, if you check the code, when i use "RunAction sModule, oneIteration" the output is different and when i dont use "RunAction sModule, oneIteration" the output is different, the code is run only on the Second ROW.